# Android java.lang.OutOfMemoryError with Jar file

Tags: java, android, heap-memory

I get OutofMemory error in my Android App. Let me explain the background.

I have an function call to modem side so had to import framework Jar. When I tried to export my Apk, the eclipse gave heap error. However, I increased the JVM heap size and exported Apk. Now, I have deployed App on device and once in 50 trials I get OutofMemory crash and log says -error at code like:

byte[] arr = new byte[bytes];

or creation of new object.

I am confused as in- how to keep App from crashing. 
Is this happening because of Jar file or because of any non GC collected references that are hanging around. I have list in couple of places. How do I de-reference them?

Please educate me, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: How big is the array? An `OutOfMemoryError` should occur if the allocation failed even /after/ a GC run.

Comment: If it happens in your app AFTER you execute an operation a few times, it sounds (to me) like a memory leak in your code.